# How to add a custom column in Woocommerce Admin with ACF field and make it sortable?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have creaded an ACF field for product categories. I would like to add a column in the admin panel (on product categories page) which displays the value of this ACF. This column should be sortable.
If the ACF field is empty it must show as blank.
The acf field is alpha numeric.